# How can I concatenate the lines of dialogue while doing Natural Language Processing on a book

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, nlp

I am working on a sentiment analysis project of a book. I am using nltk.vader.sentimentintensityanalyzer to record the sentiment polarity of paragraphs in the Harry Potter series.

To create paragraphs and remove the line breaks I did:

```
text_file = open('HP1 Sorcerer of Stone.txt', 'r')
text = str(text_file.readlines())   
text.replace('\\n"', "").replace("\'", "").replace(" , ","")
```

This breaks the book down into paragraphs. The problem arises when it comes to dialogue.

Dialogue has the same paragraph breaks in between each character's words

```
' "So?" snapped Mrs. Dursley. ',
' "Well, I just thought... maybe... it was something to do with... you 
know... her crowd." ',
' Mrs. Dursley sipped her tea through pursed lips. Mr. Dursley wondered 
whether he dared tell her he\\d heard the name "Potter." He decided he 
didn\\t dare. Instead he said, as casually as he could, "Their son -- 
he\\d be about Dudley\\s age now, wouldn\\t he?" ',
' "I suppose so," said Mrs. Dursley stiffly. ',
' "What\\s his name again? Howard, isn\\t it?" ',
' "Harry. Nasty, common name, if you ask me." ',
```

How can I edit my breakdown methods so dialogue stays together as one element? The dialogue as a whole will then be used as a single input into the intensity analyzer.

Comment: You will need to develop a solution that can detect if two different paragraphs of dialog are from the same speaker or from two different speakers. You might want to use the fact that in English, a paragraph ends with a quote mark (") when the next paragraph is no longer part of the dialog or is the start of another character's dialog.